# ngFor not working with child property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with angular 2 `ngFor`

Model class:

```
export class PaginationPage<T> {
  content: Array<T>;
}
```

in component:

```
  page: PaginationPage<Blog>;
  blogs: Array<Blog>;

  ...  
  this.blogs = page.content;
```

in template:

`<div *ngFor="let blog of blogs">` : worked

`<div *ngFor="let blog of page.content">` : not working. Error : Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

Comment: Please provide a plunker or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because by the time `page.content` is executed, `page` is `undefined`. To avoid that you can use the safe-navigation(elvis) operator (`?`):

```
<div *ngFor="let blog of page?.content">
```